# Set object properties in loop parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse.com javascript SDK and I'm trying to set some fields of the object in the loop, but only those fields which I am creating in the loop are not getting saved in parse also it is not giving me any error.

**CODE:**

```
var room = new Room();
room.id = params.roomId;

var rate = new Rate();
rate.set('room', room);                
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {    
    rate.set("rate" + i, params.price); // this fields are not getting saved                   
}
rate.save(null, {
    success: function(rate) {                     
        params.success(Response.SaveSuccess);
    },
    error: function(rate, error) {
        console.log('ERROR SAVING RATE: ' + error.message);
        params.error(Response.InternalServerError);
    }
});
```

After successful response, I can see only room field in database

Comment: are you getting something like  { rate0: 'undefined'. ... } or are the complete rows not there?

Comment: Thank you, Amit for your reply but complete columns are not there

Comment: please create a jsfiddle and share. :)

Comment: can you show your Rate object

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to set values in rate object seems a little weird. The first argument of "set" method of Parse.Object accepts only column name enclosed in inverted commas. So following is the only solution of updating an object in Parse Js:

```
rate.set("rate", params.price);
```

P.S. You need to elaborate what exactly you want to achieve in your code so that a proper solution can be posted.

Thanks